# Rewriting a for-loop to use it with "parallel"

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I am trying to rewrite a for-loop (that works great) and run it as parallel but i having all sorts of problems. Here is my for loop

```
function no_sam {
    filename=$(basename "$file")
    extension="${file##*.}"

    if [ $extension = "sam" ];
      then
        filename="${filename%.*}"
        feat_out=$filename.out
        htseq-count -f $types -r "$pos" -m "$mode" -i "$attribute" -s "$strand" -t "$feature" -a "$qual" "$file" "$input_gff" > "$feat_out"
        grep -v "_" "$feat_out" > temp && mv temp "$feat_out"
        mv "$feat_out" "$counts_folder"
    elif [ $extension = "bam" ];
      then
        filename="${filename%.*}"
        feat_out=$filename.out
        htseq-count -f $types -r "$pos" -m "$mode" -i "$attribute" -s "$strand" -t "$feature" -a "$qual" "$file" "$input_gff" > "$feat_out"
        grep -v "_" "$feat_out" > temp && mv temp "$feat_out"
        mv "$feat_out" "$counts_folder"
    fi    
}

for file in "${multi[@]}"; do 
  no_sam
done
```

And when i replaced the for loop with GNU parallel, i am getting error

```
"${multi[@]}" no_sam | parallel 

testfile.sam: command not found
```

Comment: Run your script through shellcheck.net and `bash -x`.

Comment: I already did. It is a problem with how i am running the "parallel" software.

Comment: Did you fix the concerns reported by shellcheck?

Comment: Yes i did fix those errors

Answer (score 0):

Try this (based on https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Using-shell-variables and https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Calling-Bash-functions):

```
function no_sam {
    file="$1"
    filename=$(basename "$file")
    extension="${file##*.}"

    if [ $extension = "sam" ];
      then
        filename="${filename%.*}"
        feat_out=$filename.out
        htseq-count -f $types -r "$pos" -m "$mode" -i "$attribute" -s "$strand" -t "$feature" -a "$qual" "$file" "$input_gff" > "$feat_out"
        grep -v "_" "$feat_out" > temp && mv temp "$feat_out"
        mv "$feat_out" "$counts_folder"
    elif [ $extension = "bam" ];
      then
        filename="${filename%.*}"
        feat_out=$filename.out
        htseq-count -f $types -r "$pos" -m "$mode" -i "$attribute" -s "$strand" -t "$feature" -a "$qual" "$file" "$input_gff" > "$feat_out"
        grep -v "_" "$feat_out" > temp && mv temp "$feat_out"
        mv "$feat_out" "$counts_folder"
    fi    
}
export -f no_sam

parallel no_sam ::: "${multi[@]}"
```

From the way you try to use GNU Parallel I think you will benefit from spending an hour walking through `man parallel_tutorial`. 
Your command line will love you for      it.